# How to target a value?

Tags: html, css

I want to target the `any date`  selection box but can't seem to find the right selector. It's a value "Any Date".

my code:

```css
label[for="searchdatetimes"] {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
!-- Search by date section start -->
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <label for="search_datetimes">Any dates</label>
  <select name="search_datetimes[]" id="search_datetimes" class="event-manager-category- 
    dropdown" data-placeholder="Choose any date…" data- no_results_text="No results match" data- multiple_text="Select Some Options">
    <option value="">Any Date</option>
    <option value="datetime_today">Today</option>
    <option value="datetime_tomorrow">Tomorrow</option>
    <option value="datetime_thisweek">This Week</option>
    <option value="datetime_thisweekend">This Weekend
    </option>
    <option value="datetime_thismonth">This Month
    </option>
    <option value="datetime_thisyear">This Year</option>
    <option value="datetime_nextweek">Next Week
    </option>
    <option value="datetime_nextweekend">Next Weekend
    </option>
    <option value="datetime_nextmonth">Next Month
    </option>
    <option value="datetime_nextyear">Next Year</option>.
  </select>
</div>
!-- Search by date section end --
</div>
<!-- /row -->
<div class="row">
  <!--
```

Page is: https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/

I want to target the drop down box `any date`

Tried this too.

```
a [target~="Any Date"] {
background-color: yellow;
border-radius: 20px;
border: 3px #000 solid;}
```

Nothing.

Comment: your `for` attribute is actually `search_datetimes`

Comment: label[for="searchdatetimes[]"] {

Comment: Why are you trying to set a border-radius without setting a visible border, background colour, or anything else that would make the border show?

Comment: It doesn't work even with border-color. Try in Fiddle

Comment: @fcalderan doesn't work.... Try in Fiddle...

Comment: @user11446526 as you can see it works as expected: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbXXqV (of course as suggested before, you should define a border in order to see the border-radius)

Comment: @fcaldetan. Oh sorry, I want to target the box.... `any date`

Comment: @fcalderan my bad, I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: So what you're looking to target is this line: `<option value="">Any Date</option>'? Or the whole selection box?

Comment: @Quentin trying to target value. Please see updated question.

Comment: Please see updated question.....

Comment: @Christopher Bennet the whole selection box to make it have a border-radius please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
select{
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

To your CSS

So, to better answer your initial question, the "Selector" you were trying to target was, appropriately, in this case, `select`.

You could also do it by id `#search_datetimes` if you needed to target just that element (if there are others).

Comment: You can also add `outline: none;` to get rid of that ugly blue outline when you select the box (because the outline doesn't accept the curved radius).